# C# 3 collection problem

Tags: collections, c#-3.0

Why in C# 3 I can do this:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable() {
 Columns = { "1", "2", "3" } };
```

But I can't do this:

```
 class Person {
    int Id { get; set; }
}
class Program    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v = new List<Person> { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is not implicit conversion from int to Person. If you were to define an implicit conversion for Person, that should work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=VS.100).aspx

Note in the example that a double value is implicitly convertable to a Digit type. You could define an implicit conversion for int to Person.

Answer (score 0):

Neither 1, nor 2, nor 3 are Person objects.

You could, though try:

```
var people = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Id = 1 }, new Person() { Id = 2 } , new Person() { Id = 3 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because and integer is not the same as a `Person` object, and the `Id` is a property that needs to be assigned to.

```
var v = new List<Person>();
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var p = new Person() {
        Id = i;
    }
    v.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: the question is: why in the first method I don't need to instance new dataColumns. Why the C# understing "1", "2" and "3" as DataColumn objects

Comment: Because of the implicit conversion I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Because the data table is not explicitly defining the object type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the constructor to actually instance it. In your code you are basically saying that Person is of type int and this is not the case, the variable inside is.

You can do something like this to achieve what you want.

```
var v = new List<Person>() { new Person(1), new Person(2), new Person(3) };
```

Given that you have a constructor that accepts an int.

Like this one:

```
 public Person(int id)
 {
     Id = id;
 }
```

Comment: @Rodolfo oh, and you can do the DataTable/Columns one because Columns can hold string variables, as is the case in your example.